# Include another project's qmake file in my qmake's project

Tags: c++, qt, compilation, qmake, qwt

I'm tired of having to compile [Qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) (or any other Qt project for that matter) separately every time when something changes, such as the version of Qt or the architecture. So:

I would like to add the make file of Qwt to my project, such that the files of Qwt, that get compiled, go into my shadow build folder, where I can link with them easily without having to modify my qmake pro file.

**How can I do that?**

Apparently including the qmake file with `include(../Qwt/qwt.pro)` in my project doesn't do it. Doing this will make Qt search for Qwt files in the project's qmake file's directory.

There's not much documentation provided about that. All I could find is one page which talks very briefly about it.

Thank you for any efforts.

Comment: We used ant for this. Ant has support for engaging qmake and qt's metacompilers.

Comment: @JosephMalicke Apparently there are multiple projects called ant. Could you provide a link?

Comment: Apache ant, http://ant.apache.org. Build system for Java, but can be used with other languages too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think all you need is `subdirs` project template.

Example: In my repo I have 3 projects in 3 different folders. Folders struct:

```
MyProject\
    MyProject.pro
    Project_1\
        Project_1.pro
    Project_2\
        Project_2.pro
    Peoject_3\
        Project_3.pro
```

In root directory I have project with template `subdirs` (MyProject.pro):

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS = \
    Project_1 \
    Project_2 \
    Project_3 

Project_3.depends = Project_1 Project_2
```

Then I build MyProject.pro, it compiles all projects to shadow build directory. Then I rebuild only projects that I change. When I need rebuild all projects, I buld MyProject.pro. No need to modify any .pro files.